# Unidentifiable Class Function Copy

Tags: c++, class, pointers, game-engine, software-design

So, I am currently working on a text-based RPG, and I've run into an odd issue working on the character's inventory. I am getting the following error:

`qualified-id in declaration before '(' token`

This error is located at the following line of code in my `Inventory.cpp` class:

`void Inventory::addItem(Item *I){...}`

Of course, I realize that this isn't enough information to go by, so here is all the coding for both `Inventory.h` and `Inventory.cpp`:

In `Inventory.h`:

```
 #ifndef INVENTORY_H
 #define INVENTORY_H

 #include "Item.h"
 #include <string>

 const int BACKPACK_SIZE = 16;

 class Inventory
 {
     public:
         Inventory();

         void addItem(Item *I);

         std::string getInventory();

         Item *backpack[BACKPACK_SIZE];
     protected:

     private:
 };

 #endif // INVENTORY_H
```

In `Inventory.cpp`:

```
#include "Inventory.h"


 Inventory::Inventory(){
     for(int i = 0; i < BACKPACK_SIZE; i++){
         backpack[i] = nullptr;
     }
 }

 std::string Inventory::getInventory(){
     std::string allItems = "";
     int counter = 1;
     for(int i = 0; i < BACKPACK_SIZE; i++){
          if(backpack[i] == nullptr){
             continue;
          }
          else{
              allItems += (counter + ".) " + backpack[i]->getName() + "\n");
              counter += 1;
          }

     return allItems;
 }

 void Inventory::addItem(Item *I){ //THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR APPEARS
     for(int counter = 0; counter < BACKPACK_SIZE; counter++){
         if(backpack[counter] == nullptr){
             backpack[counter] == I;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

I've done my research, yet I simply cannot figure what on earth I am doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated! Side note: it would be appreciated if people would not spend their time commenting on other things I could change about my coding, but rather stick to this specific issue. Thank you!

Comment: This sort of error is often a clue that something is wrong in the previous function.

Comment: I haven't tried compiling the code, but aren't you missing a closing brace in the for loop in Inventory::getInventory()?

Comment: I hate to say it but the problem would be more obvious if you lined up your braces. So called Allman style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question will likely be closed as a typo, but I'd like to illustrate a comment from @john that may help you.  (While also answering your question)

```
 std::string Inventory::getInventory()
 {
     std::string allItems = "";
     int counter = 1;
     for(int i = 0; i < BACKPACK_SIZE; i++)
     {
          if(backpack[i] == nullptr)
          {
             continue;
          }
          else
          {
              allItems += (counter + ".) " + backpack[i]->getName() + "\n");
              counter += 1;
          }

     return allItems;
 }
```

Your code has been reformatted here so that opening and closing braces are indented to the same level.

You may notice that it's much more apparent that you are getting your error because of a missing brace.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that I overlooked that. I scanned my code up and down so many times haha. Well thank you for that recommendation; it does indeed make total sense why one should use your format over the format that I was using. Thanks again!